# Isn't every non-unit element irreducible?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ denote a commutative ring. $r\in R$ is called **irreducible** if $r\notin R^{\times}, r\ne 0$, and if $r = ab\Rightarrow a\in R^{\times} \vee b\in R^{\times}$. All right, but isn't every non-unit element $r \in R$ irreducible, since $r=1\cdot r$, and $1\in R^{\times}$?

I guess I am wrong, but don't know where I'm wrong.

Kind regards,
MathIsFun

Comment: Counterexample: in $\mathbf Z$, $6=2\cdot 3$ is not irreducible.

Comment: You're missing the *universal* quantifier on the implication, i.e. *every* factorization of $r$ must be trivial (one factor is a unit), i.e. $r$ has only trivial factorizations.

Comment: I wonder why the explicit $r\ne 0$ is included. Given that $0=0\cdot 0$ and $0\notin R^\times$, that should be covered by the last condition, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No: $r$ is irreducible iff *every* decomposition $r=ab$ has the property that $a\in R^*$ or $b\in R^*$.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much! :-)

Comment: In addition to Tony's answer: you are right that every element has *at least one* such decomposition (in the ring of integers: every number is divisible by 1 and itself) but having the property that *every* decomposition is of this form is quite special. For instance 6 is not irreducible because it can be written as 2*3. Of course it can *also* be written as $1*6$ and as $(-1)*(-6)$ but the decomposition $6 = 2*3$ is of special interest to us because it shows $6$ is non-irreducible.

Comment: Okay, but if I can ask another question: Why do we consider $r\notin R^{\star}$?

Comment: @Vincent: Good example!

Comment: You are essentially asking (in your second question) 'why is 1 not considered a prime number?' but in the more general context of commuative rings. I think in the specific case of numbers there is some great discussion about that here on MSE. I will try to find a link

Comment: Here it is: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/120/101420

Comment: I also really like this answer in the more general, commutative ring case: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1173808/101420

Comment: I appreciate the last link as well! :-) Thanks again.

Comment: PS: I clicked on "automatically move this discussion on chat" and there was an auto-comment stating that "Let us continue discussion in chat.". I deleted the comment now. :-)